# Google Map API v3 arrow zoom level

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying draw polygon arrow using Google Map APT V3. See code below. The problem is when I zoom out the map arrow head remain same. Any way to adjust the zoom level of arrow head?

```
 var myCoordinates = [
new google.maps.LatLng(54.065836, -7.415771),
new google.maps.LatLng(53.219191, -7.261963)
];
        var polyOptions = {
            path: myCoordinates,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 1,
            strokeWeight: 3
, icons: [{ icon: { path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_OPEN_ARROW,  scale: 2 }, offset: "100%"}]
        }
        var it = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
        it.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have an event listener for the `zoom_changed` event on the map, which adjusts the scale property on the icon Symbol object.